# "Object does not exist at location" Storage exception when Uploading image to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I keep getting this error and I have no idea where the problem is. I've tried the solutions suggested in similar topics but nothing worked for me.

```
FirebaseStorage storage;
StorageReference storageReference;
storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
storageReference = storage.getReference();

private void uploadImage() {

    if(filePath != null)
    {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        final StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());


        ref.putFile(filePath)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            HashMap<String,String> h = session.getUsersDetailsFromSession();
                            String uid = h.get("uid");
                            String titre = title.getEditText().getText().toString();
                            String tim = time.getEditText().getText().toString();
                            String desc = description.getEditText().getText().toString();
                            String img = String.valueOf(uri);
                            if(titre.equals("") || tim.equals("") || desc.equals("") || lat.equals("") || lon.equals("") || img.equals(""))
                            {
                                openDialogErr();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Reclamations rec = new Reclamations(uid,titre,desc,tim,lat,lon,img);
                                String key = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().getKey();
                                DatabaseReference recl = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Reclamations").child(key);
                                recl.setValue(rec);
                                openDialogSucc();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Reclamation.this, "Failed "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot
                            .getTotalByteCount());
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the complete stack trace for the error, as you can find it in the logcat output? It also helps if you indicate what line in the code you shared raises the exception.

Comment: What does "e.getMessage()" return?

Comment: @AlexMamo it's in the title mate

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't know how to do that.
And the ref.putFile(filePath) is the line that's raises the exception

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get+the+complete+stack+trace+for+an+error+in+android